# java springでtomcatがエラーで起動しない

Tags: java, spring

コンソールにこのような表記が出てエラーがでて起動できません。
どのようにすればいいでしょうか。

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2021/10/08 09:05:05:084 INFO - o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.shutdown Shutting down ExecutorService
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

他のアプリケーションが8080番ポートを使用していて、競合していますね。1番に考えられるのは、シャットダウンし忘れているSpring Bootアプリケーションでしょうか。次のコマンドで8080番ポートを使用しているプロセスを確認して、

```
lsof -i :8080
```

問題無ければ、以下のコマンドで終了させればいいと思います。

```
kill -9 [PIDの数字]
```

もちろんSpringアプリケーションのポート番号を8080以外にして起動してもOKです。

※Windowsであればタスクマネージャーなどで同様の対応をすればいいです（コマンドでもできますが）。

参考：
https://web.plus-idea.net/on/windows-netstat-port-confirm/